# $i$ in Green functions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, complex-numbers, greens-functions, propagator

This sounds like a dumb question in my mind but I can't find an answer anywhere so I'll ask it anyway. Why on the [Wikipedia article on Green function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) is written that $$LG(x,s)=\delta(x-s)$$ but on Peskin&Schroeder I find that it is $$(i\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu-m)S(x,y)=i\delta(x-y)$$ for fermions and $$(\partial^2-m^2)D(x,y)=-i\delta(x-y)$$ for scalars? Is Green equation with or without the $i$, with or without the minus? How can I understand when  is which?

Comment: The first one is the so-called "mathematician's GF of a differential operator", while the 2nd and 3rd come from physics conventions (Fourier transformations).

Comment: @DanielC ok, but which conventions? If I want to study the Green equation for the Euclidean fermion for example, what sign should it have? Should it have an i or not? $(-\partial_\mu\gamma^\mu-m)S_E(x,y)=?$